# Counting 100 Random Numbers

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, random

I am trying to generate 100 random numbers between 0 and 9, and display the count for each  number

Is this solution correct? I want to improve, what could I have done better?

```
java.util.Scanner k = new Scanner(System.in);

int[] numbers = new int[100];

for (int i = 0;i<numbers.length;i++)
{
    numbers[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
}

int [] counts = new int[10];

for (int i = 0;i<numbers.length;i++)
{
    counts[numbers[i]%numbers.length]++;
}

for (int i=0;i<counts.length;i++)
{
    if (counts[i]>1)
        System.out.println(i+1+" Generates: "+(counts[i])+" times");
    else
        System.out.println(i+1+" Generated: "+(counts[i])+" time");
}
```

Comment: Unless you have an issue/error in your code it is generally best to post this sort of question over at CodeReviw: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Please clarify title.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [codereview.se]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have overthought this, you only need one array - of `10` values (for the range `0 - 9` there are ten unique values), generate one hundred values in that range, and increment the value in the array (that is your *count of numbers*), then loop to display. Something like,

```
int[] numbers = new int[10];
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    int ndx = (int) (Math.random() * numbers.length);
    numbers[ndx]++;
}
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    System.out.printf("%d was generated %d times.%n", i, numbers[i]);
}
```

And in Java 8+ you might write the above with `IntStream` and lambda(s) like

```
int[] numbers = new int[10];
IntStream.range(0, 100).forEach( //
        x -> numbers[(int) (Math.random() * numbers.length)]++);
IntStream.range(0, numbers.length) //
        .forEachOrdered(x -> System.out.printf( //
                "%d was generated %d times.%n", x, numbers[x]));
```

Comment: Wow great solution, you must be a pro!